# Please add the latest Knockout version (3.4.2)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-snippets

In supporting Knockout questions, I noticed that the snippets only includes up to version 3.2.0 and now we're up to 3.4.2.

Answer (score 3):

Done.  Versions 3.4.0 and 3.4.1 were also added.